# Convert a IP to Hex by Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am writing a script to convert a IP to HEX. Below is my script:

```
import string
ip = raw_input('Enter IP')
a = ip.split('.')
b = hex(int(a[0])) + hex(int(a[1])) + hex(int(a[2])) + hex(int(a[3]))
b = b.replace('0x', '')
b = b.upper()
print b
```

My Problem is that for IP like 115.255.8.97, I am getting this:

Answer Coming : 73FF861

Expected Ans :  73FF0861

Can anyone is clever enough to tell me what mistake I am making.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`hex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) function does not pad with leading zero.

```
>>> hex(8).replace('0x', '')
'8'
```

Use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format) with `02X` format specification:

```
>>> '{:02X}'.format(8)
'08'
>>> '{:02X}'.format(100)
'64'
```

---

```
>>> a = '115.255.8.97'.split('.')
>>> '{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'.format(*map(int, a))
'73FF0861'
```

Or you can use [`binascii.hexlify`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) + [`socket.inet_aton`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> import socket
>>> binascii.hexlify(socket.inet_aton('115.255.8.97'))
'73ff0861'
>>> binascii.hexlify(socket.inet_aton('115.255.8.97')).upper()
'73FF0861'
```

Comment: This looks very good. Is there any method in which I can enter more than one line as input to raw_input()?

Comment: @user2922822, You can iterate `sys.stdin` to get all lines. Or repeat calling `raw_input()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import socket, struct

# Convert a hex to IP
def hex2ip(hex_ip):
    addr_long = int(hex_ip,16)
    hex(addr_long)
    hex_ip = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack(">L", addr_long))
    return hex_ip

# Convert IP to bin
def ip2bin(ip):
    ip1 = '.'.join([bin(int(x)+256)[3:] for x in ip.split('.')])
    return ip1

# Convert IP to hex
def ip2hex(ip):
    ip1 = '-'.join([hex(int(x)+256)[3:] for x in ip.split('.')])
    return ip1

print hex2ip("c0a80100")
print ip2bin("192.168.1.0")
print ip2hex("192.168.1.0")
```

Comment: Please do not give bare code answers. Also provide an explanation for what the code is doing.

Comment: hex2ip(hex_ip) will covert a hex to IP,  ip2bin(ip) will convert IP to bin , ip2hex(ip) will convert IP to hex

Answer (score 2):

Since hex don't have leading leading zeros you can use `zfill(2)`

```
import string
ip = raw_input('Enter IP')
a = ip.split('.')
b = hex(int(a[0]))[2:].zfill(2) + hex(int(a[1]))[2:].zfill(2) + hex(int(a[2]))[2:].zfill(2) + hex(int(a[3]))[2:].zfill(2)
b = b.replace('0x', '')
b = b.upper()
print b
```

We are taking the hex number only with `[2:]` (remove '0x') and then we are adding 2 leading zeros only if needed.

Example output:

```
Enter IP 192.168.2.1
C0A80201
```

Example output:

```
Enter IP 115.255.8.97
73FF0861
```

Edit1:

by @volcano request you can replace with list comprehensions:

```
b = "".join([hex(int(value))[2:].zfill(2) for value in a])
```

Comment: Wow, you really typed this all in> How about some list comprehension?

Answer (score 2):

Since python v3.5 you can just do:

```
import socket
socket.inet_aton(ip).hex()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typebytes

Answer (score -1):

```
>>>import binascii
>>>import socket
>>>binascii.hexlify(socket.inet_aton('115.255.8.97'))
'73ff0861'
>>>binascii.hexlify(socket.inet_aton('10.255.8.97'))
'0aff0861'
```

In above IP to hex conversion output, if the output start with '0' ex. 0aff0861 then I want to  delete the 0 and output should looks like as aff0861. Is there any direct method available in conversion.

Comment: Could you put your question into a comment ? The thing is that putting  a question as an answer is misleading to the reader. (At least I was mislead ;)